# Reusing factory function from Base (producing a vector of unique_ptr)

Tags: c++

I am writing some classes, deriving from each other and providing a factory function to produce a vector of unique pointers to class (I am using a factory function for the vector because of resource allocations and unique pointers because Base is big).
Derived is restricting a member of Base and providing a function that only makes sense with this restriction. I didn't want to use Templates in this case, because there are only a few cases, each needing their own specialization.
Given are the factory function for Base and also a conversion Constructor from Base to Derived (which is trivial right now, but might not stay that way). I am not sure how to best reuse the factory function from Base in Derived.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using std::vector;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::make_unique;

class Base
{
public:
    Base( int value ) : m_value( value ) {/*complex code to construct Base*/}

    static vector<unique_ptr<Base>> makeVector( bool value, size_t count )
    {
        /*
        complex to code to prepare construction of Bases
        */
        vector<unique_ptr<Base>> out;
        out.reserve( count );
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {
            out.push_back( make_unique<Base>( value ) );
        }

        return out;
    }
private:
    bool m_value;
};

class Derived : Base
{
private:
    class _constructor_tag {};
public:
    Derived() : Base( 42 ) {}
    explicit Derived( Base&& rhs, _constructor_tag ) : Base( std::move( rhs ) ) {}; //only Derived can use this

    ////////////
    //Function i am trying to implement right now
    ////////////
    static vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> makeVector( size_t count )
    {
        vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> out;
        out.reserve( count );
        for ( unique_ptr<Base>& base_ptr : Base::makeVector( 42, count ) )
        {
            out.push_back( make_unique<Derived>( std::move( *base_ptr.get() ), _constructor_tag{} ) );
            base_ptr.release();
        }
        return out;
    }

    void doSomething() {/*only makes sense with m_value=42*/}
};

int main()
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Maybe just writing
`out.push_back( make_unique<Derived>( std::move( *base_ptr.release() ), _constructor_tag{} ) );`
would be better?
Both variants are not 100% exception safe.
Maybe there is also a better way to reuse the factory in general.
Or a better way to write such a specialization as a whole.

Comment: Why do you refer to such a non-intuitive approach at all? Are you really not able to redesign your class hierarchic in a way that your pseudo derived `makeVector`-method doesn't depent on its base class counterpart?

Comment: I could probably give Base and Derived constructors with a common signature and write a protected templated makeVector function, that gets called by the public makeVector function of Base and Derived with the right parameters. However that would make the code larger (probably neglectable), but mainly it would make Base depend on Derived, because if creating a vector of Derived ever needs some additional initialization it would need to be conditionally executed in the templated makeVector. Did you have something particular in mind on how to make this redesign?